# Literature/documentation on two cooperating processes using a flag for lock-free shared memory

Tags: design-patterns, concurrency

Is there any other documentation/discussion about the following design pattern (I'm not sure what it is called) from a well-known source? I'm almost 100% sure that the following will manage data safely between two (not more than two) processes, but would feel much better if I could find some more detailed information on why it works from a reputable source.

---

Suppose I have two processes A and B that are executing in parallel. They share the following data structure (in pseudo-C code):

```
struct Shared
{
    bool ownedByA
    Otherstuff otherstuff;
}
```

I can use the following pair of state machines to manage this shared data safely:

A:

```
state A.A (data is owned by A), entered on startup:
    read/modify/write "otherstuff"
    when done, goto A.Adone

state A.Adone
    set ownedByA to false
    goto state A.B

state A.B (data is owned by B):
    if ownedByA is true, goto state A.A
    otherwise stay in state A.B
```

B:

```
state B.A (data is owned by A), entered on startup:
    if ownedByA is false, goto state B.B
    otherwise stay in state B.A

state B.B (data is owned by B):
    read/modify/write "otherstuff"
    when done, go to B.Bdone

state B.Bdone:
    set ownedByA to true
    goto state B.A
```

We must ensure A.A's writes to "otherstuff" and A.Adone's write to ownedByA are in strict sequence ordering w/r/t memory visibility. Similarly for B.B and B.Bdone.

at startup:

```
1. Initialize ownedByA to true, A to the A.A state, B to the B.A state
2. start running state machines 
(ensure that 1. happens-before 2.)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this follows any pattern as it makes A and B highly dependent. A better solution would be the Mediator pattern with an intermediary object managing the state of each client object.

Comment: maybe design pattern is a wrong word... yes, I have a system where A and B are highly dependent. This is intended to be used in an embedded system where high-level synchronization primitives are unavailable, and the alternative of disabling interrupts is disadvantageous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Th. J. Dekker's solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm), mentioned by E. W. Dijkstra in his [EWD1303 paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1303.html).
[image]

> And then something profound and lovely happened. By analyzing by what
>   structure of argument the proof obligations could be met, the
>   numerical mathematician Th.J. Dekker designed within a few hours
>   the above solution together with its correctness argument, and this settled the
>   contest.
>   **In the above solution, the pair "c1,c2" implements the mutual 
>   exclusion, while "turn" has been introduced to resolve the tie when the
>   two processes simultaneously try to enter their critical sections.**

Comment: yay! cool, most good concurrency algorithms trace back to or through Edsgar Dijkstra.

Comment: Consider adding a link to the wikipedia page for Dekker's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm

Comment: Interesting -- I've been staring at information on Dekker's algorithm to try to figure out the differences between this and what I wrote above (why does he need 3 flags and I only have 1), and it looks like in my case there are 2 overall "ownership" states (depending on the "ownedByA" flag) with some additional transients, whereas in Dekker's algorithm there are 3 "ownership" states (either nobody is in a critical section, or process 1 is, or process 2 is). Maybe I'll call mine the "hot potato" algorithm. :-)

Comment: Ah: a further read into Dijkstra's "Cooperating Sequential Processes" shows the first solution in section 2.1 (http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD01xx/EWD123.html#2.1.%20A%20Simple%20Example%2e) is what I was looking for. This is deemed unacceptible to Dijkstra because it ping-pongs between processes 1 and 2 synchronously, but for my purposes it does what I want within my state machines. Answer accepted because it is really close + got me to the right place, along w/ learning other information.

Comment: @Jason, IMO it's better to post the above comment as an answer to your question, and accept it later. Anyway, EWD papers are cool and full of gems :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's a Dining philosophers problem with only two philosophers and one fork.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem